# Google analytics Measurement Protocol mobile allowIDFACollection and enableAdvertisingIdCollection

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I am creating a unity application and I use google analytics but without using the IOS, Android or unity sdk, instead I use requests using Google analytics Measurement Protocol.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid

What I want to do is equivalent to the following, but cannot find how to do this using the measurement protocol.

```
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

or

```
t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
```

This link contains how to do it in android/ios, but not using the measurement protocol.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en&utm_id=ad#app

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that's supported in the Measurement Protocol as it's outside of the scope of what the Measurement Protocol does. That data gets sent using a different mechanism and is joined on the back end at processing time.